# File permission "b" of /var/lib/docker/volumes/backingFsBlockDev

Tags: linux, backup, docker, rsync

I want to backup my files from a raspberry pi (rasbian) to my USB stick type (ext4) using backup software (RaspiBackup) but i'm getting an error.

It looks like an authorization issue.

The error:
"rsync: mknod var/lib/docker/volumes backingFsBlockDev : Operation not permitted".

The backupsoftware offers 2 types of backup:
"Rsync" is the suggested backuptype but "tar" is also a possibility.

Using the first option I get an error message but when I use the 2nd option it works fine.

But I want to make the backup using rsync.

It seems that docker is changing certain permissions on those directory/files and therefore a "super user" has no access/rights.

Comment: It's not a file. It's a block device. Backing it up serves no purpose. You are not backing up the data on the device.

Comment: Having looked into this further, it appears that `backingFsBlockDev` is related to how Docker does filesystem quotas. It’s a reference to the block device that holds `/var/lib/docker`. I think the device node is recreated every time Docker starts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there a way to prevent or test this? And if so, can this be arranged from the backup software or at the Linux/docker level?

Comment: Prevent what, exactly? Your could just exclude it from your backup, that might work. Perhaps create a VM with Docker and see if it recovers from the file being deleted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with docker but I meant how could I prevent, if your guess is correct, that the device node is recreated every time Docker starts. Should I exclude the entire folder (var/lib/docker) from the backup?

Comment: You cannot prevent it. You must decide for yourself what you want to backup.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna play with it. Thanks for your help